# "Authentication is required to update SMART data from" in 16.04

Tags: nvidia, 16.04, login-screen, ubuntu-gnome

I upgraded to 16.04 [Ubuntu Gnome]. I am using a Lenovo Y700 with a GTX960M.

After suspend or closing the lid I ended locked outside the login after that message appeared. 
It happened twice today, I suspect the problem arises when closing the lid, **not** when using the suspend button hitting alt button while hitting the power button onscreen.
Using open source NVIDIA version 364.19 nvidia-364.

Comment: Same pb. on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's caused by lm-sensors. 
Click on the thermometer indicator (which is lm-sensors) -> Preferences -> Providers.
Then **untick 'Enable support of udisks2'**. That seems to make it go away. ([Source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2274234&s=f5ea8645a4a232a9fd439cb38b65699d&p=13306318#post13306318))

[image: screenshot]

Comment: In case there is no thermometer icon: the desktop app is called  `psensor`, can be started from command line or via unity/gnome

Comment: Would've *never* guessed this was the culprit. Thank you!

Comment: What is udisk2?  I've also suddenly been seeing this weirdness since I've been suspending the machine instead of shutting down.  If I uncheck it, _what am I losing?_

Comment: seems to work on Ubuntu 20.04 as well 

Comment: Any idea how to do this via the command line? It's impossible to get to this dialog with the SMART data pop-up happening every few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Original here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2274234&page=2&p=13522130#post13522130

this is caused by PolKit, and if you do want the sensors, you can write a custom rule:

Depending on your distro, create a custom polkit rule.
Ubuntu 20.04 and up

```bash
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/
sudo touch /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/00_user_hacks.rules
```

Ubuntu 18.04 and lower

```bash
sudo mkdir -p /etc/polkit-1/rules.d
sudo touch /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/00_user_hacks.rules
```

The file is actually JavaScript, which makes it pretty easy to modify if you have that experience.

```javascript
const CUSTOM_PERMISSIONS = {
    // fixes udisk2 issue with lm-sensor where it prompts for root password after suspend -> resume
    "org.freedesktop.udisks2.ata-smart-update": polkit.Result.YES
};

polkit.addRule(function (action, subject) {
    if (subject.user == "YOUR_USERNAME_HERE" && action.id in CUSTOM_PERMISSIONS) {
        return CUSTOM_PERMISSIONS[action.id];
    }

    return polkit.Result.NOT_HANDLED;
});
```

You can just add other custom rules into the CUSTOM_PERMISSIONS object and it will be handled.

Comment: Do I need to restart a service for this new rule to be taken into account ?

Comment: @SebMa you would likely have to restart since other systems interact with polkit, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Issue still present in Ubuntu 20.

The [JavaScript fix presented by @WiR3D](https://askubuntu.com/a/1231821/618353) does not work as is.
The location of the `rules.d` directory has changed and can be found in `/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/00_user_hacks.rules`.

Editing the file in this new location and going to standby mode does seem to fix the issue, but after some time, the password is required again when going again in standby mode.

I will try to investigate more deeply this issue and update this discussion once an appropriate fix is found.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `psensor` caused the problem. Just kill `psensor`.